# How can i ignore the characters between brackets?

Tags: python, assert

Example:
The hardcoded input in the system:

```
Welcome to work {sarah} have a great {monday}!
```

The one i get from an api call might differ by the day of the week or the name example:

```
Welcome to work Roy have a great Tuesday!
```

I want to compare these 2 lines and give an error if anything but the terms in brackets doesn't match.

The way I started is by using `assert` which is the exact function I need then tested with ignoring a sentence if it starts with `{` by using `.startswith()` but I haven't been successful working my way in specifics between the brackets that I don't want them checked.

Comment: Probably too naive but how about `all(x==y for x, y in zip(a.split(), b.split()) if not x.startswith('{'))` assuming `a` is the string with the brackets and `b` the other one??

Comment: The problem with doing anything too general here, is that if you have a mostly correct message with junk words just around where the brackets are - you will not catch this. My suggestion if the brackets always translate to a single word, is to split each sequence into the words that make it and then compare each word - skipping words that are brackets in the original. If not, it's a harder problem and you may have to accept some potential for error. @Ev.Kounis shows a good way to do it if is a 1:1 match for brackets:word subtitutions.

Comment: I suggest taking a stab with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Check out the [regular expression howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Comment: Slightly more robust version `len(a.split())==len(b.split()) and all(x==y for x, y in zip(a.split(), b.split()) if not x.startswith('{'))`. Regex is the way to go here imho

Comment: This sounds vaguely like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you obtain the actual patterns, or deduce them from a sufficiently large amount of sample sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are good for matching text.

Convert your template into a regular expression, using a regular expression to match the `{}` tags:

```
>>> import re

>>> template = 'Welcome to work {sarah} have a great {monday}!'

>>> pattern = re.sub('{[^}]*}', '(.*)', template)
>>> pattern
'Welcome to work (.*) have a great (.*)!'
```

To make sure the matching halts at the end of the pattern, put a `$`:

```
>>> pattern += '$'
```

Then match your string against the pattern:

```
>>> match = re.match(pattern, 'Welcome to work Roy have a great Tuesday!')
>>> match.groups()
('Roy', 'Tuesday')
```

If you try matching a non-matching string you get nothing:

```
>>> match = re.match(pattern, 'I wandered lonely as a cloud')
>>> match is None
True
```

If the start of the string matches but the end doesn't, the `$` makes sure it doesn't match. The `$` says "end here":

```
>>> match = re.match(pattern, 'Welcome to work Roy have a great one! <ignored>')
>>> match is None
True
```

edit: also you might want to [**`escape`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) your input in case anyone's playing silly beggars.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't think I can use this method because I'm basically dealing with NLP (natural language processing) where this is an example of a sentence input but there are thousands of possible inputs the user might give and hardcoding each and every template possibility is not an option.

Comment: @Sarah I see, so we can't rely upon `sarah` and `monday` being fields. I have fixed to use `re.sub`

Comment: Works beautifully for the cases I've tested so far thanks.

Comment: `Welcome to work Roy have a great one! <ignored>` does not match the `Welcome to work {sarah} have a great one!` template, but your answer will say that it does.

Comment: Thanks @vaultah, have fixed with an ending `$`

Answer (score 1):

You can make copies that do not include anything that has brackets around it and compare those. It is relatively easy with regular expressions. As a function, it could look like this:

```
import re

# compare two strings, ignoring everything that has curly brackets around it
def compare_without_brackets(s_1, s_2, p=re.compile(r"{.*?}")):
  return p.sub('', s_1) == p.sub('', s_2) 

# example
first = 'Welcome to work {sarah} have a great {monday}!'
second = 'Welcome to work {michael} have a great {tuesday}!'

print(compare_without_brackets(first, second))
>> True
```

edit: reworked my answer after seeing I got something wrong. It works now in a way that everything with curly brackets around it is replaced with a universal match. Now you can compare the hardcoded version with any returned from the API and still get either `True` or `False`, depending on whether they match or not.

```
import re

# compare a hardcoded string with curly braces with one returned from the API
def compare_without_brackets(hardcoded, from_API, p=re.compile(r"{.*?}")):
  pattern = re.compile(p.sub(r'(.*)', hardcoded))
  return pattern.match(from_API) is not None

# example
first = 'Welcome to work {sarah} have a great {monday}!'
second = 'Welcome to work michael have a great tuesday!'

print(compare_without_brackets(first, second))
>>>> True
```

Comment: Won't work because the hard-coded version has brackets but the API response doesn't.

Comment: Then I guess Peter's answer should do.

Comment: I gave it another try. Left my initial answer to avoid confusion. .. and it seems I came up with the same solution as Peter.